# Error in Search Server Express 2008

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, search-server

I've installed Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express, and as a part of it, WSS 3.0
And for 6 month, it runs without fail, until yesterday. The search site refuses to perform search, and Search Central Administration gives cryptic error message

```
HRESULT: 0x80040D1B.
```

Looking at event log, I noticed there's a thousand error message from "Office Share Point Server" and "Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 (timer)"
Here's the error message.

```
Application Server Administration job failed for service instance 
Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance 
(6503413d-4031-4c19-aca7-927076e0b33f).

Reason: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040D1B
.
.
.
```

Searching the internet leads me to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812030751/http://geekswithblogs.net/mhamilton/archive/2006/12/21/101809.aspx), which describes method I'm too afraid to try since it's an old article and there's a high probability that all the documents that I've uploaded would be deleted.

Searching for **HRESULT: 0x80040D1B** gives me the impression that maybe the error has something to do with permission.

So, my question is this. How can I get Search Server working again? How do I ensure that is not a permission problem?

My Server Configuration

```
OS  : Win Server 2003 R2 SE 64
RAM : 8 Gigs
Web Server and SQL Server are in the same box, without any server farm
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the password of any of your SharePoint service accounts recently?  Follow the steps in the following article to update the SharePoint passwords: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838

Comment: Unfortunately No. My Sharepoint service account is a domain account, and It's working properly.

Comment: I agree with Alex... everything I have seen on this error centers around the passwords needing to be updated.  It won't hurt anything and it should help.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you haven't changed any passwords. However why don't you try following the steps in [KB article 934838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838) anyway. Provided you have all of the service account and password details, this won't hurt anything and will ensure your password configuration is correct.

Also, is there any chance the passwords have expired?